# Jest (NestJS) - How to mock method dependencies?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

In the codes below I am trying to test the *"someMethodToTest"* method, but the *"someDependencyMethod"* method should be mocked. However, the demonstrated approach is not working as the exception *"I MUST NOT BE CALLED!"* is being launched every time I run the tests with Jest...

```
 FAIL  src/user-files/user-files.service.spec.ts (0.123 s)
  ● SomeClassToTest › test someMethodToTest

    thrown: "I MUST NOT BE CALLED!"
```

**NOTES:** I - This is a NestJS application; II - Tests using Jest; III - The code is simplified to facilitate understanding.

I've tried many, many approaches...

**QUESTION: What is wrong with the code? Why does the "someDependencyMethod" method keep being called?**

**Thanks!**

**[Ref(s).:** [How to Mock dependencies with Jest](https://dev.to/this-is-learning/how-to-mock-dependencies-with-jest-457l) **]**

**some-mdl-to-test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SomeDependencyClass } from './some-dependency-mdl';

@Injectable()
export class SomeClassToTest {
  async someMethodToTest(someMethodToTestArg: string): Promise<string> {
    const someDependencyMethodOutput: string = await new SomeDependencyClass().someDependencyMethod(someMethodToTestArg);
    return someDependencyMethodOutput;
  }
}
```

**some-dependency-mdl.ts**

```
export class SomeDependencyClass {
  async someDependencyMethod(someDependencyMethodArg: string): Promise<string> {
    throw 'I MUST NOT BE CALLED!';
    // ...
    // SOME LOGIC!
    // ...
    return "SOME_VALUE_A";
  }
}
```

**some-mdl-to-test.service.spec.ts**

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { SomeClassToTest } from './some-mdl-to-test.service';
import { SomeDependencyClass } from './some-dependency-mdl';

describe('SomeClassToTest', () => {
  let someClassToTest: SomeClassToTest;
  let someDependencyClass: SomeDependencyClass;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [SomeClassToTest, SomeDependencyClass],
    }).compile();
    someClassToTest = module.get<SomeClassToTest>(SomeClassToTest);
    someDependencyClass = module.get<SomeDependencyClass>(SomeDependencyClass);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(someClassToTest).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('Test someMethodToTest!', async () => {
    const someDependencyMethodOutputMock = "SOME_VALUE_A";
    const someMethodToTestInputMock = "SOME_VALUE_B";
    const someMethodToTestOutput = "SOME_VALUE_A";
    const someDependencyMethodPromise: Promise<string> = Promise.resolve(someDependencyMethodOutputMock);
    jest.spyOn(someDependencyClass, 'someDependencyMethod').mockImplementation(() => someDependencyMethodPromise);
    const someMethodToTestOutputToCheck = await someClassToTest.someMethodToTest(someMethodToTestInputMock);
    expect(someMethodToTestOutputToCheck).toEqual(someMethodToTestOutput);
  });
});
```

Comment: **Does anyone have any idea what's going on?** 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is how you are injecting your dependencies. In the sense that, with the code you provided, you are not injecting the dependencies.

If your `SomeClassToTest` would look like:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeClassToTest {
  constructor(
    @Inject(SomeDependencyClass)
    private readonly someDependencyClass: SomeDependencyClass
  ) {}

  async someMethodToTest(someMethodToTestArg: string): Promise<string> {
    return await this.someDependencyClass.someDependencyMethod(
      someMethodToTestArg
    );
  }
}
```

Your tests could look something like:

```
describe("SomeClassToTest", () => {
  let someClassToTest: SomeClassToTest;

  const mockReturnValue = "SOME_VALUE_A",
    mockDependencyClass: SomeDependencyClass = {
      someDependencyMethod: async (): Promise<string> => {
        throw new Error("ups");
      },
    };

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    jest
      .spyOn(mockDependencyClass, "someDependencyMethod")
      .mockImplementation(async () => mockReturnValue);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        SomeClassToTest,
        { provide: SomeDependencyClass, useValue: mockDependencyClass },
      ],
    }).compile();

    someClassToTest = module.get(SomeClassToTest);
  });

  it("should be defined", () => {
    expect(someClassToTest).toBeDefined();
  });

  it("Test someMethodToTest!", async () => {
    const someMethodToTestOutputToCheck =
      await someClassToTest.someMethodToTest("something");

    expect(someMethodToTestOutputToCheck).toEqual(mockReturnValue);
  });
});
```

Let me know if something needs more clarifying :)

Going through Nest [overview](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps) and [fundamentals](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) should give you enough to understand the code above

Comment: Yes, *"the problem is how you are injecting your dependencies"*! Thanks! 
In my case I solved with something a little different. I added the "constructor" like this `constructor(private readonly someDependencyClass: SomeDependencyClass) {}` and using `return await this.someDependencyClass.someDependencyMethod(someMethodToTestArg);` the same way you did. 
**But, the big question is: Why does it only work with the addition of the "constructor"?** 

Comment: Well, in this specific case, and looking at the code in your question, every time you would call `someMethodToTest`, you were `new SomeDependencyClass().someDependencyMethod(someMethodToTestArg)`. This would create a new instance of an object inside you function, and you can't/shouldn't spy/mock that way. The way Nest works (and Angular too, you can read [this](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action) and [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-dependency-injection/), ...

Comment: ...  as Nest is inspired by Angular), it instantiates an instance of an object and shares that as an Injectable were specified